# Embedded Jetty and Slf4j configurations

Tags: java, eclipse, slf4j, executable-jar, embedded-jetty

I have a project running with embedded Jetty 7 that must logging in file. I am using Slf4j + Logback. When I run with Eclipse, it works as expected, but when I export to a jar file and try to run in a prompt, the configurations of logback are skipped.

I use this to generate the file:

```
RolloverFileOutputStream os = new RolloverFileOutputStream("C:/logs/yyyy_mm_dd_project.log", true);
PrintStream logStream = new PrintStream(os);
System.setOut(logStream);
System.setErr(logStream);
```

I also put the logback.xml in src/main/resources.

What is my mistake? Tks

Answer (score 0):

Fixed following this:

[Configure logging for Jetty's maven plugin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7168214/configure-logging-for-jettys-maven-plugin)

I changed the pom.xml and generate the jar by Maven. Problem fixed.